# Crosstab to identify the number of id with multiple modalities

Tags: python, pyspark, crosstab, contingency

I cant resolve this since this morning,

I have a dataset with 2 columns : id_campaign and id_client

[image]

I need to know the number of client in a couple of campaign,
he an exemple :

I want a dataset like this :

[image]

But with this command I have 0's or I want the number of crossed campaign

Have you got any ideas please ?
I can explain more if necessary

Edit :
I can do it in PySpark or in Python

And I tried multiple combinations of aggregation with groupBy() ; pivot_table() ; and partitionBy() without satisfying results

Comment: I don't get your expected output, do you mind explaining it?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I want the number of client contacted by 2 campaigns for every couple of campaign
by example in the cells column "5211" row "5210" I want the number of client who has a line with the id camp '5211' AND '5210' (in the example the client "0000162100" should be counted for one

Comment: I see, please put your sample input and expected output in table format? that would help us a lots on troubleshooting and debugging